# Reading key value pair from hash table

Tags: c#, hashtable, namevaluecollection

I am storing below in my web config.

```
<add key="* Cancellation" value="Allow"/>
```

Now i am loading this into hast table

```
 NameValueCollection tempCollection = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection(CONFIG_SECTION);
 Hashtable localCollection = new Hashtable();
 localCollection.Add(Collection.GetKey(index), tempCollection );
```

now i am trying to read the value from hash table by providing key.

My key can have anything like Pending, canceled, Endorsed or declined before Cancellation so i kept * in key. * means it can have anything.

```
value = tempCollection["Pending Cancellation"]
```

but my value is not populating correctly. Value is coming as null

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: `"* Cancellation" != "Pending Cancelleation"`, so no surprise it isn't found. What behavior are you expecting?

Comment: Is there any way so that it will give appropriate value. Before cacellation anything can come like pending or endorsed or declined

Comment: corrected my post. no spelling mistake was not the problem

Comment: Are you kidding me. After everything was done these guys put question on hold

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do that, you have to look for all keys that are like the string that you're looking for. Something similar to this:

```
    foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in hashtable)
    {
        if(DictionaryEntry.Key.Contains(" Cancellation")){value = DictionaryEntry.Value;}
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Ben this is what i am trying to achive. Is this possible using hash table Or the only option is to switch to dictionary.

Comment: Keep in mind that this will over write value each time it matches *Cancellation in the key.

Comment: That is fine with me but is this achivable through hash table

Comment: I updated it for a hashtable.

Comment: If this solves your question, please mark it as so.

Comment: Is this possible with namevaluecollection

Comment: I am getting error 'System.Collections.DictionaryEntry' does not contain a definition for 'key'

Comment: Sorry, please capitalize to Key. See updated code.